# Baking procedural material

Tags: texture-baking, procedural

So the problem i have is that when baking a procedural material, i get an inconsistent output for the image.

This the procedural material

[image: procedural material]

This is the baked material:

[image: baked material]

Any ideas on how to resolve the issues would be much appreciated.

Comment: What resolution have you baked to? Is there an opportunity in your case, to make a tileable texture instead, giving you a higher resolution per tile?

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=Z88boOBO" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Z88boOBO/)

Here's the blend file, it's not the same one as I used in the image above, but still the has the same issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quality of your bake depends on the number of render samples you have configured for your renders, the resolution of your target image and the size of your texture's features. If the 'lines' making up the crosses on your texture are very thin and/or the number of samples in your render are quite low then there is an increasing chance that the baking will miss those features. Also, there will be blurring resulting from the resolution of the image that you are baking to.

Try increasing the number of samples and/or increasing the resolution of the target image to see if that produces a cleaner bake.

Comment: Increasing the resolution of the target image resolved it. Much appreciated for the pointers.